# Add a different Spanish definite article to a cross-reference depending on the kind of theorem it refers to

Tags: cross-referencing, cleveref, ifthenelse, spanish

I'm using the package `cleveref` to automatically print the name of the kind of "theorem" of a reference via the `\Cref` macro. Since I'm writing in Spanish, the most natural way to refer to a theorem is by adding a definite article before the reference (that is, I want to refer to "**the** Theorem 1.1" instead of just "Theorem 1.1"). The problem is that in Spanish, the form of the definite article depends on the grammatical gender of the word it modifies.

So let’s say I have something like this:

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{teo}{Teorema}
\newtheorem{prop}{Proposición}

\begin{document}

    \begin{teo} \label{first}
        A theorem
    \end{teo}

    \begin{prop} \label{second}
        A proposition
    \end{prop}
    
    El \Cref{first}, el \Cref{second}.

\end{document}
```

The output looks like this:

```
Teorema 1. A theorem
Proposición 1. A proposition
    El Teorema 1, el Proposición 1.
```

"teorema" means 'theorem', "proposición" means 'proposition', and "el" means 'the'. However, since "proposición" is a feminine noun, it takes the feminine article "la" instead of "el". So the last line should be `El Teorema 1, la Proposición 1`. I want a way to do this automatically, so that `\somemacro{ref}` prints `el Teorema n` if the `ref` points to a theorem and `la Proposición n` if `ref` points to a proposition. I tried adding the following to the preamble:

```
\newcommand{\ElCref}[1]{% capitalized
    \ifthenelse{%
        \equal{\nameCref{#1}}{Proposición}%
    }{%
        La \Cref{#1}%
    }{%
        El \Cref{#1}%
    }%
}
\newcommand{\elCref}[1]{% non-capitalized
    \ifthenelse{%
        \equal{\nameCref{#1}}{Proposición}%
    }{%
        la \Cref{#1}%
    }{%
        el \Cref{#1}%
    }%
}
```

and then `\ElCref{first}, \elCref{second}.` inside the document. However, this produces the same output as before. More specifically, it looks like `\ifthenelse{\equal{\nameCref{ref}}{Name}}{1}{0}` always evaluates to `0`, even though `\nameCref` seems to be working fine. I gather this probably has to do with how TeX does string comparisons, but I don't know enough to figure out how to fix it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `\crefformat` (for the lower case version) and `\Crefformat` to add the correct article.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\newtheorem{teo}{Teorema}
\newtheorem{prop}{Proposición}

\Crefformat{teo}{El #2teorema~#1#3}
\crefformat{teo}{el #2teorema~#1#3}
\Crefformat{prop}{La #2proposición~#1#3}
\Crefformat{prop}{la #2proposición~#1#3}


\begin{document}

\begin{teo} \label{first}
A theorem
\end{teo}

\begin{prop} \label{second}
A proposition
\end{prop}
    
\Cref{first}, \cref{second}.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Your best bet is to use the `\crefformat` commands. e.g.,

```
\crefformat{teo}{el teorema} 
\Crefformat{teo}{El teorema}
```

and the base `\cref`/`\Cref` commands for the references.

As for why your attempt doesn't work, it's because the `\nameCref` command does not expand at the top level to the expected string, but rather to a series of commands that ultimately gives the string. This is a common issue for people trying to do string comparisons on the results of LaTeX macros.

Comment: Does that mean that doing a string comparison with `\namecref{ref}` is impossible? Your answer and egreg's work, but I might want to define some other cross-referencing commands which depend on the kind of theorem in a similar way. For example, the preposition "de" ('of') contracts with "el" but not with "la", so I'd want "del teorema 1" but "de la preposición 1".

Comment: Effectively yes. If you look at how the `\namecref` command is defined, even fully expanded it would not be simply the text. It's a limitation of the TeX programming model. You might be able to do something more involved following the logic of the `\namecref` command to get at the information you want.